# React - Track changes on state to perform a patch (partial model) api request

Tags: reactjs

I'm struggling with being able to manage an state in order to keep track of user changes and being able to send an Patch request with a partial model, with only the changed values. Basically, I'm dealing with a complex model with nested objs and arrays, and will be displayed as a form, and user will be able to edit any field and through a Save button should send a patch request with only the modified fields.

Any suggestions, guidelines?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just keep track of the original state and the modified state separately. Then use any of the abundance of diff packages out there to generate a diff patch.